# adding two polynomials using dynamic arrays

Tags: c

I have the following code written. After i run the code it works fine until it tries to excecute the function add2Poly. Thereafter i get a segementation fault. I am new to programming so i cant understand what is  causing it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct poly{
double power[5];
double* coeff;
};
struct poly add2Poly(struct poly add1, struct poly add2)
{
  struct poly p3;
  p3.coeff = malloc(5 * sizeof * p3.coeff);
  printf("We will add the two polynomials and put the result in a third polynomial p3.");
  int size1 = sizeof(add1.coeff);
  int size2 = sizeof(add2.coeff);
  for(int i = 0; i < size1; i++)
    {
      int power = add1.power[i];
      for(int j= 0; j < size2; j++)
    {
     
      if( power == add2.power[j])
        {
              p3.coeff[i] = add1.power[i] + add2.power[j];
          p3.power[i] = add2.power[j];
        }
    }
    }
  return p3;
}

int main(){
struct poly p1;
p1.coeff = malloc(5 * sizeof * p1.coeff);
double a;
printf("Please enter a double value for poly1 coeff:");
  scanf("%lf", &a);
  double b;
printf("Please enter a double value for poly1 coeff:");
  scanf("%lf", &b);
p1.coeff[1] = a;
p1.coeff[2] = b;

printf("Power of poly1: ");
scanf("%lf", &p1.power[1]);
printf("Power poly2: ");
scanf("%lf", &p1.power[2]);

printf("p1: %.1fx^%.1f", p1.coeff[1], p1.power[1]);
printf("+ %.1fx^%.1f\n", p1.coeff[2], p1.power[2]);


struct poly p2;
p2.coeff = malloc(5 * sizeof * p2.coeff);
double c;
printf("Please enter a double value for poly2 coeff:");
  scanf("%lf", &c);
  double d;
printf("Please enter a double value for poly2 coeff:");
  scanf("%lf", &d);
p2.coeff[1] = c;
p2.coeff[2] = d;

printf("Power of poly1: ");
scanf("%lf", &p2.power[1]);
printf("Power poly2: ");
scanf("%lf", &p2.power[2]);

printf("p2: %.1fx^%.1f", p2.coeff[1], p2.power[1]);
printf("+ %.1fx^%.1f\n", p2.coeff[2], p2.power[2]);

 struct poly p3;
 p3.coeff = malloc(5 * sizeof * p3.coeff);
p3 = add2Poly(p1,p2);
printf("p3: %.1fx^%.1f", p3.coeff[1], p3.power[1]);
printf("+ %.1fx^%.1f\n", p3.coeff[2], p3.power[2]);
}
```

to be precise it gives me the following error:
`segmentation fault(core dumped)`. I assume it has something to do with the p3 struct but i am not sure.

Comment: What line of the code is causing the fault?

Comment: `sizeof(add1.coeff)` will return the size in bytes of a pointer to double on your system. You need to path the array length into your functions or store it in the structs

Comment: May I ask why you chose an array of 5 for the powers and a dynamically allocated one for the coefficients?

Answer (score 0):

You want to initialize `power` by `add1.power[i]`(line 18) when you have not assigned a value of `add1.power[i]`, because at the first iteration `i = 0`
Then you have not assigned a value of `add1.power[0]`, but only `add1.power[1]` and `add1.power[2]` (add1 = p1) and you want use it,
which means that conditional jump depends on uninitialised value : `if( power == add2.power[j])` line 22, `power` is NULL also `add2.power[j]`
Delete lines 14 and 15 it does not serve you because
`sizeof(add1.coeff)` return the size in bytes of a pointer to double on your system : the result = 8 here.
You'll have an invalid read, your array poly.power and poly.coeff have a size of 5 while you want to read up to 8 values.
that's why you have this error `segmentation fault(core dumped)`, Because you want to access a memory location that was not allocated to it.

Starting with your idea, if you want your code to work change the loop interval to 1 and 3: because only `poly.power[1]`, `poly.power[2]`, `poly.coeff[1]` and `poly.power[2]` are initialized.
Also in line 24 & 25 Do the sum of coefficients and not the sum of power to get the coefficients of the 3rd polynomial.

The way you define the structure of your polynomial can be changed, knowing only the degree of the polynomial. You can avoid the nested loop in your add2Poly function too.

I hope that will heplp you !

Look at the following code:

```c
struct poly add2Poly(struct poly add1, struct poly add2)
{
    struct poly p3;
    p3.coeff = malloc(5 * sizeof *p3.coeff);
    printf("We will add the two polynomials and put the result in a third polynomial p3.\n");
    int size1 = sizeof(add1.coeff);// to delate
    int size2 = sizeof(add2.coeff);// to delate
    for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
    {
        int power = add1.power[i];
        for (int j = 1; j < 3; j++)
        {

            if (power == add2.power[j])
            {
                p3.coeff[i] = add1.coeff[i] + add2.coeff[i];// do the sum of coefficients and not the sum of power 
                p3.power[i] = add2.power[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return p3;
}
```

here is an optimized proposal of your problem

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct poly
{
    int degree;
    double *coeff; // the number of coefficient is equal to degree +1
};

struct poly add2Poly(struct poly p1, struct poly p2)
{
    struct poly p3;
    struct poly p_min_degree;
    if (p1.degree > p2.degree)
    {// the degree of the polynomial p3 is the one which has the greatest degree between p1 and p2
        p3 = p1;
        p_min_degree = p2;
    }
    else
    {
        p3 = p2;
        p_min_degree = p1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= p_min_degree.degree; i++)
    {
        p3.coeff[i] += p_min_degree.coeff[i];
    }
    return p3;
}

struct poly create_poly()
{// Ask the user to enter the degree of the polynomial and (degree +1) coefficients
    struct poly p;
    printf("Power of the polynomial : ");
    scanf("%d", &p.degree);
    p.coeff = malloc((p.degree + 1) * sizeof *p.coeff);
    for (int i = 0; i <= p.degree; i++)
    {// Read a double as coeff
        printf("Enter the coeff x^%d : ", i);
        scanf("%lf", &p.coeff[i]);
    }
    return p;
}

void display_poly(struct poly p)
{// Displays a polynomial p passed as a parameter
    //Display example: p degree 2
    //p = + 3.00x^2 + 4.00x^1 + 2.00x^0
    printf(" p = ");
    for (int i = p.degree; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        printf("+ %.2lfx^%d ", p.coeff[i], i);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    struct poly p1 = create_poly();
    display_poly(p1);
    struct poly p2 = create_poly();
    display_poly(p2);
    struct poly p3 = add2Poly(p1, p2);
    printf("The sum of p1+p2 is :");
    display_poly(p3);
}
```

Comment: I agree with the above answer it is correct to add coeffs instead of adding powers. This is what caused the segmentation fault,
Looks good other than that!